# Issues installing fabric-sdk-rest

Tags: npm, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to install hyperledger fabric sdk rest server. I have cloned [fabric-sdk-rest](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest) repo and installed the prerequisites but when trying to run "npm link" in packages/loopback-connector-fabric I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/loopback-connector-fabric
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/loopback-connector-fabric'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/loopback-connector-fabric'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink \'/usr/lib/node_modules/loopback-connector-fabric\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/loopback-connector-fabric' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2018-02-12T22_24_45_379Z-debug.log
```

This is what happens if I run it with sudo:

```
> pkcs11js@1.0.13 install /home/user/Documents/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/loopback-connector-fabric/node_modules/pkcs11js
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/user/Documents/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/loopback-connector-fabric/node_modules/pkcs11js/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.8.0-36-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/Documents/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/loopback-connector-fabric/node_modules/pkcs11js
gyp ERR! node -v v9.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.13 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2018-02-12T22_26_40_864Z-debug.log
```

This is done in Ubuntu 16.04. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this errors too. After a while trying all kind of insane things to get it running I came into account that the problem was I was installing npm modules as superuser globally. This conflicts with hyperledger*.

Solutions is `$: sudo npm uninstall -g ***` for every module you just installed as superuser.

Then you need to install the modules ***not as superuser***. This are some advices.
If installing Hyperledger Composer using Linux, be aware of the following advice:

- Login as a normal user, rather than root.
- Do not `su` to `root`.
- When installing prerequisites, use `curl`, then unzip using sudo.
- Run prereqs-ubuntu.sh as a normal user. It may prompt for root password as some of it's actions are required to be run as
- Do not use npm with sudo or su to root to use it.
- Avoid by all means installing node modules globally as root.

If you're running on Ubuntu, you can download the prerequisites using the following commands:

```
curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/prereqs-ubuntu.sh
chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```

Next run the script - as this briefly uses `sudo` during its execution, you will be prompted for your password.

```
$: ./prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```

This is the best way

Or you can visit this page and follow the prereqs installation guide.

[Prerequisites for Ubuntu](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html#ubuntu)

and finally follow this link to continue the installation it works just fine.

[Install development tools](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html)

This is the latest update

Hope this helps